# create the new sheet in phpexcel and set the cell value

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to use phpexcel to set the template purchase order .
I have set column 25 to 43 is for details of purchase item. It mean it will retrieve data from database and set all the value in column 25 to 43 .As addition ,these column only can fit for 6 item. I am facing problem when the purchase item is too many and cannot fit into the column that i had set.
My code is work,but it is too long. Anyone have a better solution?
after create both sheet,i have to set the other cellvalue one by one in both sheet.It make the code become very long.Appreciate for who can help.

```
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT purchasematerial.PONum,purchasematerial.QuoNum,purchasematerial.date,           material.product,purchasematerial.description,purchasematerial.unit_price,purchasematerial.UOM,purchasematerial.qua        ntity ,purchasematerial.amount FROM purchasematerial INNER JOIN material ON        purchasematerial.product=material.id where PONum='$PONum'");
   $col=25;
  $num=1;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 if($col<43){
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA11', $row['PONum']);
 $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA12', $date->format('d-M-y'));
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I45', '=AA12+7');
 $QuoNum=$row['QuoNum'];
 if ($QuoNum=='' || $QuoNum== null)
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I47', "N/A");
else
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I47', $row['QuoNum']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$col, $num);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$col, $row['product']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$col, $row['description']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S'.$col, $row['unit_price']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('V'.$col, $row['UOM']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Y'.$col, $row['quantity']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB'.$col, $row['amount']);
$col=$col+3;  
$num++;
}

else{

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$col=25;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA11', $row['PONum']);
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA12', $date->format('d-M-y'));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I45', '=AA12+7');
$QuoNum=$row['QuoNum'];
if ($QuoNum=='' || $QuoNum== null)
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I47', "N/A");
else
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I47', $row['QuoNum']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$col, $num);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$col, $row['product']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$col, $row['description']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S'.$col, $row['unit_price']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('V'.$col, $row['UOM']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Y'.$col, $row['quantity']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB'.$col, $row['amount']);
$col=$col+3;  
$num++;
}
}

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I45')->getNumberFormat()-    >setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AC1', 'WEEKNUM(I45)');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q44', 'TOTAL');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Y44','RM');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB44', '=SUM(AB25:AB43)');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('Q44')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('Y44')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AA44')->getFont()->setBold(true);

 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I45')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AC1', 'WEEKNUM(I45)');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q44', 'TOTAL');
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Y44','RM');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB44', '=SUM(AB25:AB43)');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('Q44')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('Y44')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AA44')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use the fluent interface.

Instead of

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I47', $row['QuoNum']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$col, $num);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$col, $row['product']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$col, $row['description']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S'.$col, $row['unit_price']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('V'.$col, $row['UOM']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Y'.$col, $row['quantity']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB'.$col, $row['amount']);
```

do

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I47', $row['QuoNum'])
    ->setCellValue('A'.$col, $num)
    ->setCellValue('B'.$col, $row['product'])
    ->SetCellValue('J'.$col, $row['description'])
    ->SetCellValue('S'.$col, $row['unit_price'])
    ->setCellValue('V'.$col, $row['UOM'])
    ->SetCellValue('Y'.$col, $row['quantity'])
    ->SetCellValue('AB'.$col, $row['amount']);
```

so that you're not constantly calling `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()`

For setting the second sheet, as the cells are identical to the first; you could create a function to set the cell values and just call that function twice (basic PHP 101). Alternatively, you could set the cells for the first sheet, then clone that sheet and set the clone as the second sheet.

Comment: I have found another solution which is using                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(1, 23);

Comment: You realise that rows to repeat isn't doing the same thing at all; but is releated to printing options